# Не получается отправить изменения на github

Tags: git, github

Пилю свой несчастный рогалик. Сижу вечером за своим ведроидом, написал код и готовлюсь послать его в репозиторий. Однако меня ожидает облом.

```
$ git push
//Не могу, в репозитории на github есть какой-то коммит
```

И тут я вспоминаю, что редактировал на сайте README.md. Решил попробовать сделать git pull:

```
 $ git pull
 Writing objects: 69%
```

И тут гит завис. Естественно, я в замешательстве. Пробую git fetch, но он тоже зависает!

Гуглю решение, нашёл, что можно отменить свой локальный коммит. Не помогает. Так же виснет. Пытаюсь сделать git push --force. И, что характерно гит опять зависает.

Поиск удаления с гитхаба коммита не даёт результатов, ведь git pull виснет.

**Что мне делать?**

Comment: Для начала: добавить в вопрос, что показывает `git status`

Comment: `git fetch` при таких (весьма обычных, кстати) обстоятельствах вовсе не должен зависать. Вы никаких тяжёлых файлов в репозиторий не закидывали?

Comment: Неа. Больше десятков килобайт не закидывал. git status показывает то, что я могу что-то закоммитить.